# Is it ok for me to reference previous projects in my portfolio?

Tags: portfolio

I plan to build my own online portfolio. I'm a software developer, and have worked on a wide range of different projects. Some of which were public-facing websites that are live now and serve as a great example of what I can do or at least projects I've been heavily involved in.

Is it 'ok' (i.e. legal and responsible of me) to name these projects on my own website as projects I've been a part of and what contribution I've made as long as I'm explicit about the fact I did it for the company I worked for?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Did your employment contract for that company include a non-disclosure agreement that would prevent you from disclosing or discussing that company's clients? Such a provision would not be unusual for a consultancy.

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of a portfolio? The only exception might be if you have done something for government or military.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're well within your rights to show examples of the work you've completed within your portfolio, **with the possible exception of work or information that's protected by Non Disclosure Agreements.**

In those instances, it may be best for you to follow up with the company to ensure you have permission to disclose your involvement in performing the work or any other details.

Of course, it may not be likely that you'd be 'caught' presenting such information, but you'll need to cover all of your bases before making a confident decision.

In my personal experience (I am also a software developer), I've kept some project details vague enough that the person I'm speaking with has a general understanding of what the end result was, but not necessarily how it was built or who it was built for.

Ideally, your employers are going to want to know that you **have** significant experience and are able to perform the duties of the position you're applying for; They will likely understand if you're not able to share the specifics of certain projects you've been a part of.